# What is the timeline meaning in system trace instrument

Tags: ios

[image]

When i profile using system trace instrument. There is always three lines for every thread. So what does the red and blue line mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System calls are the red capsules, virtual memory faults appear as the blue capsules. The grey bar with the annotations "Blocked" and "Running" represents the thread state.

There's a WWDC session that explains https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/411

Comment: Thanks.

I have watched this session very carefully before asking this question. But still can't found the answer. thanks again.